# Wowza Cloud - CORS (hls.js)

Tags: cors, cross-domain, wowza, http-live-streaming, wowza-transcoder

I'm trying to get a stream running into a website using hls.js from the wowza cloud, but keep getting a CORS error. I know I need to change the headers on the streaming server, but where do I do that using the Wowza Cloud? All documentation only shows how to change it on the Wowza Engine.

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is now supported in Wowza Streaming Cloud. To enable:

1. From the Cloud UI, click on Advanced > Stream Targets.
2. Create a new Wowza CDN - HLS Stream Target and enable CORS for this stream target.
3. From Advanced > Transcoders, you can associate this new stream target with CORS enabled for your transcoder output.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not supported with Wowza Streaming Cloud. An alternate method for these types of pull workflows will be supported in the future (on the roadmap, no timeline).